# Sharepoint SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sharepoint, nullreferenceexception

I have a secure code block in SharePoint as following:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(rootSite))
    {
        _web = site.OpenWeb(subSite);
    }
});
```

Most of time, it works fine, but sometimes, I got this error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__2()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
   at NCS.MDA.FiMS.CreateReturnFileTask.BatchJobManager..ctor()
```

Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks

Comment: what does rooSite and subSite equal at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

At a guess your new SPSite(rootSite) is giving you a null value.

Try wrapping your method with n if statement that checks for null

```
 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(rootSite))
    {
       if(site != null)
     {
       _web = site.OpenWeb(subSite);

    }
            }
});
```

Add an else bit to the if statement and see if you can log some information to give you some feedback if you can't find out if site is null by debugging

Cheers
Truez